# Data voice call between two apple phones

Tags: messages, cellular-data, cellular-carriers

My girlfriend and I will be travelling in USA and using ATandT pay as you go sim cards while there. The only problem is that we don't get International calling.

So I want my gf to be able to use data to void call family on their iphones.

But I don't know anything about apple, so I am not sure what is the best method. What is important is that it uses data and does not default to the cellular system and cost us mucho denairo!!

Comment: So you're traveling to the USA, what country are you from?

Comment: Canada. I am using and AT and T sim with just Data and US calls because getting canadian calls is $15 more.

Comment: Look up FaceTime Audio calls.

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something obvious here or can you just use FaceTime Audio? Obviously it won't work if you use the keypad, but you can call from anywhere you have their contact card (Contacts, Phone, Messages, FaceTime, even Mail...)

You did say both parties have iDevices, right?

Comment: Note that you will have to each have an Apple ID and have FaceTime activated for Facetime Audio to work. Here is an Apple article on setting up and using using FaceTime: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204380

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to force a call to use data instead of cellular minutes, or everyone would be doing it.

One option you have is to enable Wi-Fi calling. If you are logged into a wi-fi network, you can make calls using the wi-fi. Go to Settings > Phone > Calls: Wi-Fi Calling and switch it to ON. Not every carrier allows this, so if the setting isn't there, obviously you can't use it.

You can also use Google Voice for free. You could probably get a number local to your Canadian origination and still be able to call home while you're on the road. Skype calling has a similar option. Both have apps for the iPhone.

It was brought to my attention that you can also use FaceTime audio (as the other answer suggests). I've had problems with this personally, but others have had success with it!

Comment: TMHahn, you are mistaken. See randomhead's answer!!

Comment: @JohnRamos, I've had nothing but problems using FaceTime for international calls. That's why I didn't state it as an option, but you both are right, it IS an option. Just so I know for the future, can you tell me why wi-fi calling won't work?

Comment: FaceTime audio calling has been for me much more reliable. WiFi calling takes some time to activate, and relies on your carrier to work (and some carriers' services to just plain don't work abroad). They have been unreliable and my AT&T WiFi calling has cycled on/off by itself repeatedly. FaceTime audio is system integrated and almost always turned on by default. No new accounts needed, no changes needed, nothing that needs to be turned on; it's just there, and for me it just works. What hasn't worked for you?

Comment: @JohnRamos, FaceTime is really choppy and fades in and out for me while using cellular data. I get the clearest signal from either regular cellular calling or wi-fi calling. It took me about 4 minutes to set up, but then I've had zero problems with it. No dropped calls, and no fading in and out. I'm a licensed Private Investigator, so if I'm taking a recorded statement or talking to a client, it's vital it be clear. FaceTime audio can't provide that for me. At least, not in Southern California.

Comment: Ok. I thought FaceTime Audio was obviously the best solution, but maybe I'm mistaken... I'll remove my downvote (but I can't until you edit your answer, it's `locked`!).

Comment: I don't think you're mistaken, I just think we have different experiences!